# Logical evaluation error when looping through dictionary of conditions

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm looping through a list of web pages with Scrapy. Some of the pages that I scrape are in error. i want to keep track of the various error types so I have set up my function to first check if a series of error conditions ( which I have placed in a dictionary are true and if none are proceed with normal page scraping:

```
def parse_detail_page(self, response):

    error_value = False
    output = ""

    error_cases = {

        "' pageis not found' in response.body" : 'invalid',

        "'has been transferred' in response.body" : 'transferred',
    }

    for key, value in error_cases.iteritems():
        if bool(key):
            error_value = True
            output = value

    if error_value:
        for field in J1_Item.fields:
            if field == 'case':
                item[field] = id
            else:
                item[field] = output

    else:
        item['case'] = id
        ........................
```

However I see that despite even in cases with none of the error cases being  valid, the 'invalid' option is being selected. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditions (`something in response.body`) are not evaluated. Instead, you evaluate the truth value of a nonempty string, which is `True`.

This might work:

```
def parse_detail_page(self, response):

    error_value = False
    output = ""

    error_cases = {

        "pageis not found" : 'invalid',

        "has been transferred" : 'transferred',
    }

    for key, value in error_cases.iteritems():
        if key in response.body:
            error_value = True
            output = value
            break

.................
```

(Must it be "pageis not found" or "page is not found"?)

Answer (score 1):

bool(key) will convert key from a string to a bool.

What it won't do is actually evaluate the condition. You could use eval() for that, but I'd recommend instead storing a list of functions (each returning an object or throwing an exception) rather than your current dict-with-string-keys-that-are-actually-Python-code.

Comment: Thank you . Would you mind linking to an example. I'd like to see how your approach works.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are evaluating bool(key) like you are.  Let's look at your error_cases.  You have two keys, and two values.  `"' pageis not found' in response.body"` will be your key the first time, and `"'has been transferred' in response.body"` will be the key in the second round in your for loop.  Neither of those will be false when you check bool(key), because key has a value other than False or 0.

```
>>> a = "' pageis not found' in response.body"
>>> bool(a)
True
```

You need to have a different evaluator other than bool(key) there or you will always have an error.

Comment: Thank you very much, I misunderood bool()

Answer (score 1):

Your conditions are strings, so they are not be evaluated.
You could evaluate your strings using `eval(key)` function, that is quite unsafe.

With the help of the [operator](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/operator.html) module, there is no need to evaluate unsafe strings (as long as your conditions stay quite simple).

error['operator'] holds reference to the 'contains' function, which can be used as a replacement for 'in'.

```
from operator import contains

class ...:
    def parse_detail_page(self, response):

        error_value = False
        output = ""

        error_cases = [
            {'search': ' pageis not found', 'operator': contains, 'output': 'invalid' },
            {'search': 'has been transferred', 'operator': contains, 'output': 'invalid' },
        ]


        for error in error_cases:
            if error['operator'](error['search'], response.body):
                error_value = True
                output = error['output']
        print output

        if error_value:
            for field in J1_Item.fields:
                if field == 'case':
                    item[field] = id
                else:
                    item[field] = output

        else:
            item['case'] = id
            ...
```

Comment: Thank you , I will check out the operator module.